# Show that $x_0 \in \overline{\langle M \rangle } $ if and only if $f(x_0) = 0, \; \forall f \in X^* : f|_M = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem, hahn-banach-theorem

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $M \subset X$. Show that an element $x_0 \in X$ belongs to the set $\overline{\langle M \rangle}$ if and only if $f(x_0) = 0$ for all $f \in X^*$ such that $f|_M = 0$.

**Attempt :**

First of all, clarifying that $\overline{\langle M \rangle}$ denotes the closure of the linear hull of $m \in M$, thus it is the set :

$$\overline{\langle M \rangle} = \overline{\{\lambda \cdot m | m \in M , \lambda \in \mathbb R\}}$$

I have the intuition that what we want to prove essentialy is that $\langle M \rangle$ is dense over $X$, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Other than that, I can't seem to find any other way around it, so I would really appreciate any tips or elaborations.

Comment: The definition you state about linear hull is wrong by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$No, the exercise is not about proving that $\span M$ is dense. The set $M$ could be a singleton for instance. A sketch of a proof could be as follows:

"$\Rightarrow$": Let $x\in \overline{\span M}$, then there is a sequence $x_n\in \span M$ such that $x_n\to x$. Moreover if $f|_M=0$ for some $f\in X^*$ then what can you say about $f(x)$? Use the continuity of $f$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Assume that $f(x)=0$ for all $f\in X^*$ such that $f|_M=0$. Assume that $x\notin \overline{\span M}$ then there is some ball $B(x,\delta)$ such that $B(x,\delta)\cap\overline{\span M}=\emptyset$. In particular for every $z\in \span M$ we have $\|x-z\|\geq \delta$.

We will make use of this. First notice that each $z\in \span(M\cup x)$ can be written as follows
\begin{align}
z=\lambda x+\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i m_i
\end{align}
for some $\lambda$, $\mu_i\in\mathbb K$ and $m_i\in M$. We define the operator $g:\span(M\cup x)\to\mathbb K$ as follows:
\begin{align}
g(z)=\lambda
\end{align}
It is easy to see that it is linear. Moreover $g|_M=0$  and $g(x)=1$ by definition. It is also bounded, since (assuming $\lambda\neq 0$)
\begin{align}
\frac{|g(z)|}{\|z\|}=\frac{|\lambda|}{\|\lambda x + \sum_{i}\mu_i m_i  \|}=\frac{1}{\|x+\sum_{i}\frac{\mu_i}{\lambda} m_i\|}\leq \frac 1 \delta
\end{align}
This bound trivially holds if $\lambda=0$. 
Hahn Banach now says that there is an extension of $g$, call it $f\in X^*$ satisfying $f|_{\span(M\cup \{x\})}=g$. This $f$ satisfies $f(x)=1$ while $f|_M=0$ a contradiction.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your input. Well, for the first, if $f|_M = 0 \implies f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$ ? Where does that lead ?

Comment: @Rebellos Don't you want to show that $f(x)=0$? That is what you have in your comment? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I want to show that $f(x) =0$ with $x \in M$. What we have is $x \in \overline{\text{span}M}$. I am probably missing something thought.

Comment: @Rebellos Oh I had to clarify $\text{ span } M$ is just $\langle M\rangle$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: No worries I knew that. I still don't get why the above implies that $x \in M$ for $f(x) = 0 $ (if my definition for linear hull is wrong).

Comment: @Rebellos You are talking about the first part "$\Rightarrow$", right? Then I take some $x\in \overline{\text{ span } M}$ and show that if I take $f\in X^*$ such that $f|_M=0$, then that I indeed have $f(x)=0$. As I see, that is the statement we need to prove for the implication "$\Rightarrow$". Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry for my awesome stupidness, for some reason my mind was denying basic thinking. Kindly thanks for your input, very well explained and the second part is clear for me as well!

Comment: @Rebellos I'm happy as long as you understand it! Let me know if you come up with something unclear!

Comment: Sorry for the final poke, but I have a slight difficulty at defining the desired $f$ such as it serves our purpose.

Comment: @Rebellos It is alright! I changed everything for the second part. The idea I had in mind was not right, it turned out to be difficult for nothing. Now I gave a full proof for the second part. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @Rebellos I made it clearer to read now. Let me know if it is understandable.

Comment: Yes, everything is clear now. I figured out that the initial approach was complicated and not legit because I spent some time tinkling it over my head. Thanks so much for your inputs, I really appreciate the commitment to the post.